# Calculation Aspect Ratio returning 0.0

Tags: java, aspect-ratio

I am trying to make a  method to calculate aspect ratio for resizing something.

```
public float ARC(int oHeight, int oWidth, float nWidth)
{
    float h = (oHeight / oWidth) * (nWidth);
    return h;
}
```

and to run I am using:

```
System.out.println(ARC(65, 375, 375));
```

> 64 being asigned to oHeight,
>   375 to oWidth and 375 to nWidth.

But when I test the code, the output is: 0.0?
The result is supposed to be 65

Comment: `65 / 375` equals `0`.

Comment: @ChrisMartin how do I get it to work? I need some sort of 0 check

Comment: Cast one of the `int`s to `float` so you get floating-point division rather than integer division.

Comment: @ChrisMartin Thx add it as an answer, I feel so dumb now :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(This question was already answered in [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27939819/aspect-ratio-calculation-returning-0-0/29823187#comment44276230_27939819) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27939819/aspect-ratio-calculation-returning-0-0/29823187#comment44276143_27939819) by Chris Martin but he didn't post an answer)

The problem is that you're doing **integer** division, not floating-point division, so while you expect:

```
65 / 375 = 0.17...
```

You actually get:

```
65 / 375 = 0
```

The is because the decimal part gets cut off. You need to cast the first `int` (Either first or second, but I find that most readable and least error-prone) to `float`:

```
float h = ( (float) oHeight / oWidth) * (nWidth);
```